# Raw sql in ruby on rails return relation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to use raw sql in ruby on rails to retrieve data,for faster response.
I use

```
 @test1=ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select Unique Id from device_tables")
```

Then I test it use a p tag to display it in view：

```
<p><%= @test1 %></p>
```

But instead of give me data,it displays a relation:

```
#<Mysql2::Result:0x00000008664948>
```

I want to get the content of database,store all unique ids in a array.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can try find_by_sql method.eg:

`TableName.find_by_sql"select * from table_names"`

Comment: this returns [#<NoiseDevice id: 2>, #<NoiseDevice id: 3>, #<NoiseDevice id: 9>, #<NoiseDevice id: 10>],How can I get rid of colum name and only data

Comment: This returns an array of NoiseDevise objects, not an ActiveRecord Relation.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate it using `each` or `map` to get results on view. Your current object look like this :

```
#<Mysql2::Result:0xcd3dfe0 @query_options={:as=>:array, :async=>false, :cast_booleans=>false, :symbolize_keys=>false, :database_timezone=>:utc, :application_timezone=>nil, :cache_rows=>true, :connect_flags=>-2147442171, :cast=>true, :default_file=>nil, :default_group=>nil, :adapter=>"mysql2", :database=>"GetTravelTime_Development", :host=>"localhost", :pool=>5, :username=>"root", :password=>nil, :timeout=>5000, :flags=>2}>
```

I have tried it on console for single and multiple object like this :

```
mysql_object = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select Unique Id from device_tables")
mysql_object.each{|object| puts object}
mysql_object.map{|object| puts object}
```

Comment: I tried your method but it still returns a relation,but the content change,for .each it returns #<Mysql2::Result:0x00000005f533b8>,for .map it returns #<Mysql2::Result:0x0000000834f000>